# Converting a Date to a new TimeZone in Java

Tags: java, date, timezone, simpledateformat

Converting a Java `Date` object to a specific ("target") time zone is a question that has been asked numerous times before in `StackOverflow` and the suggested solutions apparently are:

- Adjust the time (milliseconds) value of the `Date` object by the timezone offset
- Use `SimpleDateFormat` (with the timezone) to produce the desired date as a String

However, there seems to be no "plain Java" solution that parses a date string (with or without timezone) into a `Date` object and then adjusts a corresponding `Calendar` object to the target timezone, so that the "converted" date behaves in all cases in the correct way (e.g., when using the `Calendar` object to retrieve the year of the date).

The main issue is that, reasonably, **when the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern used to parse the date string does not have a timezone, the system assumes that the time is in the parsing system's timezone. If, however, the pattern does have a timezone, the time is counted from `UTC`**. So, what is needed is essentially an indication as to whether the original date string corresponds to a pattern with or without a timezone, which apparently cannot be done without analyzing the pattern itself.

The attached source code of the `TimezoneDate` class demonstrates the discrepancies.

Here is the output from running the `main()` method for 2 "original dates", the first without and the second with a timezone, when they are converted to UTC on a machine running on Pacific Standard Time (PST):

```
Original  date:         20/12/2012 08:12:24
Formatted date (TZ):    20/12/2012 16:12:24
Formatted date (no TZ): 20/12/2012 08:12:24
Calendar  date:         20/12/2012 16:12:24
Expected  date:         20/12/2012 08:12:24

Original  date:         20/10/2012 08:12:24 +1200
Formatted date (TZ):    19/10/2012 20:12:24
Formatted date (no TZ): 19/10/2012 13:12:24
Calendar  date:         19/10/2012 20:12:24
Expected  date:         19/10/2012 20:12:24
```

The correct operation is to have the "Formatted" and "Calendar" strings identical to the "Expected date" for each of the 2 example date strings ("original dates").

Apparently one needs to make a distinction between the case where the date string contains a timezone symbol (TZ) and the case where it does not (no TZ), but this means knowing the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern beforehand, which is not possible when handling a `Date` object and not the original string.

So, the question is really about whether a generic "plain Java" (no third party libraries) solution exists that does not require prior knowledge of the pattern and works correctly with the corresponding `Calendar` object.

Following is the full source code of the `TimezoneDate` class.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimezoneDate
{
    private final Date time;
    private final TimeZone timezone;
    private final Calendar calendar;

    /**
     * Creates a wrapper for a {@code Date} object that is converted to the
     * specified time zone.
     *
     * @param date      The date to wrap
     * @param timezone  The timezone to convert to
     */
    public TimezoneDate(Date date, TimeZone timezone)
    {
        this.calendar = TimezoneDate.getPlainCalendar(date, timezone);
        this.time = this.calendar.getTime();
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }

    private static Calendar getPlainCalendar(Date date, TimeZone timezone)
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timezone);

        calendar.setTime(date);

        return calendar;
    }

    private static Calendar getAdjustedCalendar(Date date, TimeZone timezone)
    {
        long time = date.getTime();

        time = time + timezone.getOffset(time) - TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(time);

        date = new Date(time);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.setTime(date);

        return calendar;
    }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return this.calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }

    public int getMonth()
    {
        return (this.calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    }

    public int getMonthDay()
    {
        return this.calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

    public int getHour()
    {
        return this.calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    }

    public int getMinutes()
    {
        return this.calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }

    public int getSeconds()
    {
        return this.calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }

    public String toCalendarDate() // The date as reported by the Calendar
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append(this.getMonthDay()).append("/").append(this.getMonth()).
           append("/").append(this.getYear()).append(" ").
           append(this.getHour()).append(":").append(this.getMinutes()).
           append(":").append(this.getSeconds());

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String toFormattedDate(boolean addTimezone) // The formatted date string
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        if (addTimezone)
        {
            sdf.setTimeZone(this.timezone);
        }

        return sdf.format(this.time);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // Each data "vector" contains 3 strings, i.e.:
        // - Original (example) date
        // - SimpleDateFormat pattern
        // - Expected date after converting the original date to UTC
        String[][] data = new String[][]
        {
            {"20/12/2012 08:12:24", "dd/MM/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss", "20/12/2012 08:12:24"},
            {"20/10/2012 08:12:24 +1200", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", "19/10/2012 20:12:24"}
        };

        Date originalDate;
        TimezoneDate timezoneDate;
        SimpleDateFormat format;
        TimeZone UTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

        for (String[] vector:data)
        {
            format = new SimpleDateFormat(vector[1]);
            originalDate = format.parse(vector[0]);
            timezoneDate = new TimezoneDate(originalDate, UTC);

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Original  date:         " + vector[0]);
            System.out.println("Formatted date (TZ):    " + timezoneDate.toFormattedDate(true));
            System.out.println("Formatted date (no TZ): " + timezoneDate.toFormattedDate(false));
            System.out.println("Calendar  date:         " + timezoneDate.toCalendarDate());
            System.out.println("Expected  date:         " + vector[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even Sun/Oracle gave up on the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date and .Calendar classes. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html) or the new java.time package in Java 8. The old classes are flawed both in design and implementation.

Answer (score 3):

## Joda-Time

Rather than use Java's `Date` you should use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class.  This allows you to carry out timezone operations in a very simple fashion, using the `withTimezone()` and `withTimezoneRetainFields()` methods depending on your particular requirements.

Comment: Sure, but the desired solution should not use any third party libraries. Just plain vanilla Java. I have clarified the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Although it is understandable, dates and times are one area where the base Java support is very broken.  If you can wait for Java 8 then JSR-310, which is the next generation of Joda, will be in the core.  In the meantime you could either use Joda or the JSR-310 reference implementation and carry out the relatively minor changes to use the core libraries when you migrate to Java 8.

Comment: Neither Java 8, nor JodaTime is an option in this case. The latter, in addition to the fact that it is a third party library, it also does not support all DateFormat patterns, which restricts its usability.

Comment: @PNS I don't understand your comment DateTime formats. Joda-Time has dozens of built-in date-time formats, built-in support for localized formats, and you may define your own formatters as well. In what way is java.util.Date/.Calendar support for formatting superior or Joda-Time's lacking?